# Using PHP to store user uploaded files in Cloud SQL

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I need to allow a small subset of users on my GAE-hosted PHP site to upload files (tarballs of python scripts, typically ~25k in size). Given the tiny footprint of each file and relative infrequency of access to this particular table, I just want to store the files in my CloudSQL DB as a varbinary or mediumblob. It also makes cleaning up old files a lot easier.

I can find a lot of docs discussing the use of cloud storage buckets, but nothing on storage into a SQL DB. var_dump ($_POST) returns the rest of the form fields (as expected) but var_dump ($_FILES) returns undefined - I suppose because this is dependent on a filesystem write for the temporary version of the uploaded file, and GAEPHP doesn't allow filesystem writes.

Any way to make this work or am I doomed to using a CloudStorage bucket and keeping the path in the table? Could I use javascript to convert the tarball to a binary stream client side and POST as text or something in a hidden field?

Appreciate any ideas!

Edit with a secondary issue: phpinfo lists file_uploads = 'Off'. I've tried setting it in php.ini as = 1 and = '1' and neither seems to take effect. Other settings changes in php.ini are taking effect. Wondering if this was listed as a configurable param in error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try direct file uploads in this case: https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2015/03/09/direct-file-uploads-for-php-5-5/

Comment: Thanks Mars - this works. My file_uploads on phpinfo now shows "on" too - looks like it only honors the .ini flag when runtime = php55.